# What ODBC driver for Sybase with Windows 8.1?

Tags: python, odbc, sybase

I've tried multiple drivers such as [FreeTDS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freetdswindows/?source=typ_redirect) and [Adaptive Server Enterprise](https://apps.state.or.us/tech/htdocs/sybase.html), both of which are not working with Windows 8.1. FreeTDS doesn't get loaded into my Data Sources Manager and Adaptive Server Enterprise doesn't fully download. I would greatly appreciate any help on how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the Sybase ASE SDK (software developer's kit) the drivers you need will be a part of that download.

Remember that ODBC drivers are 32/64 bit specific, and that the driver bitsize needs to match the application bitsize.

Comment: Sybase was bought by SAP, so you'll need to go to sap.com   You may want to download the free Developer edition, which I believe includes the SDK and ODBC driver installer you may need.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried searching on sap.com but was unable to find the free Developer edition. Could you please send me the URL?

Comment: Also, in this post (http://scn.sap.com/thread/3360231) one of the employees of SAP seems to be suggesting that there may not be any freely available ODBC driver installer.

Comment: Look for the link in the center of the page:  http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/oltp-db